# How to improve performance of this recursive function?

Tags: python, performance, recursion

I'm trying to write a function which will search str for a substr, taking into account different possibilities to write weird letters, such as æ, ø, å in danish language. For example you can search 'Ålborg' and the function will return true if there is, say 'Aalborg' in the str.

The function below works, but performance is unbearable. What would you recommend to improve performance?

```
def danish_tolerating_search(substr, str):
    '''Figure out if substr is in str, taking into account
    possible deviations in writing letters æ, ø, å.
    æ  <->  ae a ea
    ø  <->  oe o
    å  <->  aa a o
    '''

    # normalize input
    substr = substr.lower().replace('aa',u'å')
    str = str.lower()

    # normalized recursive search
    # TODO fix perfomance
    def s(substr, str):
        if str.find(substr) >= 0: return True
        if substr.find(u'æ') >= 0:
            if    s(substr.replace(u'æ','ae', 1), str): return True
            elif  s(substr.replace(u'æ', 'a', 1), str): return True
            elif  s(substr.replace(u'æ','ea', 1), str): return True
        if str.find(u'æ') >= 0:
            if    s(substr, str.replace(u'æ','ae', 1)): return True
            elif  s(substr, str.replace(u'æ', 'a', 1)): return True
            elif  s(substr, str.replace(u'æ','ea', 1)): return True
        if substr.find(u'ø') >= 0:
            if    s(substr.replace(u'ø','oe', 1), str): return True
            elif  s(substr.replace(u'ø', 'o', 1), str): return True
        if str.find(u'ø') >= 0:
            if    s(substr, str.replace(u'ø','oe', 1)): return True
            elif  s(substr, str.replace(u'ø', 'o', 1)): return True
        if substr.find(u'å') >= 0:
            if    s(substr.replace(u'å','aa', 1), str): return True
            elif  s(substr.replace(u'å', 'a', 1), str): return True
            elif  s(substr.replace(u'å', 'o', 1), str): return True
        if str.find(u'å') >= 0:
            if    s(substr, str.replace(u'å','aa', 1)): return True
            elif  s(substr, str.replace(u'å', 'a', 1)): return True
            elif  s(substr, str.replace(u'å', 'o', 1)): return True
        return False

    return s(substr, str)
```

Comment: string is the name of a module in the standard library, so think twice before using it as a variable name.

Comment: @jforberg, @KennyTM, I have different names than here in my 'real' function, this is just for example.

Comment: Do you have some test for benchmarking?

Comment: Just to be clear, "ålborg" should match to "ålbørg" or "ålbårg" or "aalborg" or "aalbørg" or "aalbårg" or "alborg" or "albørg" or "albårg", right?

Comment: @KennyTM, no but in my application it takes minutes to execute this function. So, I would like to get 10-100 times better performance.

Comment: @101100 you're right, but this is an overkill. I implemented it so, because misspelling is very frequent, and non-native-danish-speakers usually screw up the spelling and come up with ålbårg and stuff...

Comment: @KennyTM: His original question used 'string' as a variable name, which conflicts with the *standard module* 'string'. The new version uses 'str', which is even worse since it actually redefines the *built-in type*. Although python allows this, it is very bad practice.

Comment: @Halst: You may call your variables whatever you prefer, but you will confuse readers if you use already-taken names. I'm just trying to save you from the really obscure bugs you would encounter if you later decided to *import string* or make type comparions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should eliminate the recursion altogether. Instead of doing all that `find` and `replace`, you could, for example, decide upon a "normal form" of your input strings, convert them accordingly (i.e. replace those "ambiguous" characters) and do a simple

```
return substring in string_
```

Note also that you don't need to call `find` and `replace` together, the latter sufficies. If the search string isn't found, replace just won't replace anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def danish_tolerating_search(search, content):
    search = search.lower()
    content = content.lower()

    variants = {
        u'a': u'[aæå]',
        u'o': u'[oøå]',
        u'ae': u'(?:ae|æ)',
        u'ea': u'(?:ea|æ)',
        u'aa': u'(?:aa|å)',
        u'oe': u'(?:oe|ø)',
        u'\\å': u'(?:[oå]|aa?)',
        u'\\ø': u'(?:ø|oe?)',
        u'\\æ': u'(?:æ|ae?|ea)',
    }

    search = re.escape(search)
    search = re.sub(ur'[ae]a|[ao]e?|\\[åøæ]', lambda m: variants[m.group(0)], search)
    return re.search(search, content) is not None
```

I did not test its performance because OP did not release any. I'll just assume the regex engine is better optimized than calling OP's `s()` recursively  and doing lots of `.find` and `.replace`.

Here, the key letters in the search string are replaced by the possible equivalent classes in terms of regex, e.g. `Ålborg` becomes `(?:[oå]|aa?)lb[oøå]rg`. This regex should include all possible variants equivalent to `Ålborg` (ålbørg" or "ålbårg" or "aalborg" or "aalbørg" or "aalbårg" or "alborg" or "albørg" or "albårg" as mentioned by @101100's comment). Then the regex is simply searched against the context.

Comment: Very nice, more details than mine. I especially like the map in re.sub

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of a parser. Read up on things like lex and yacc, you won't need all of their functionality, but the principles still apply.

After that, use the [python re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module to match against the appropriate regular expressions. If you need more functionality, use the [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) libraries.

```
def danish_tolerating_search(substr, str):
'''Figure out if substr is in str, taking into account
possible deviations in writing letters æ, ø, å.
æ  <->  ae a ea
ø  <->  oe o
å  <->  aa a o
for all of these combinations replace with appropriate regex as in example
'''
substring = substring.lower().replace('aa', '[ae]{1,2}')
string = string.lower()
re.search(substring, string)
```

Comment: The trick will be doing the replacements without over-expanding, since _å_ can be **a** or aa or å and **a** can be a or _å_ or æ.  You will actually need 9 different replacements (for æ, ø, å, a, o, ae, ea, oe, and aa).  Once the tricky replacements are done, the `re.search` should work.  Edit: See KennyTM's answer.